# Does $f$ achieve its max on $X$?

Tags: real-analysis

Prove or disprove.

Suppose $X$ is a compact metric space and $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function for which $f^{-1}([t,\infty))$ is closed for any real $t$. Then $f$ achieves its maximum value on $X$.

I believe this is false since $f$ is not assumed to be continuous. But since the preimage of that subset of the range is closed, it makes me think that maybe it does indeed reach a maximum. I'm quite stumped. Any nudges in the right direction would be terrific.

Comment: Does $f(x)\in \mathbb R$ or $f(x)\in [-\infty ,\infty ]$ ? (what the notation $f^{-1}([t,\infty ])$ suggest...)

Comment: I believe this is the preimage of $f$ from $[t, \infty)$. @Surb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we prove that $f$ is bounded above. If not, there is a sequence of points $x_i$ such that $f(x_i) > i$ for all $i$. $x_i$, being an infinite sequence, has a convergent subsequence with limit $x$, which is contained in $f^{-1}([i,\infty))$ for all $i$, which is closed. But $\bigcap [i,\infty)$ is empty, so this cannot be the case, and we have a contradiction. Thus $f$ is bounded above.

Now let $A = \sup f$. Choose a sequence $x_i$ such that $A-f(x_i) < 2^{-i}$ for all $i$. Then this has a convergent subsequence with limit $x$, which is contained in $f^{-1}([A-2^{-i},\infty))$ for all $i$, hence is contained in $f^{-1}([A,\infty))$. Thus $f(x)=A$.

Comment: Did your proof for $f$ being bounded only prove that it is bounded above? @Matt Samuel

Comment: @user Yes. Let me clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is assumed to be bounded above thee its maximum is attained: let $M$ be teh supremum of $f$ on $X$. Then for each $n$ there exists $x_n\in X$ such that $f(x_n) >M-\frac 1 n$. By compactness there is a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ which converges to some $x$. Now $x_m \in f^{-1}[M-\frac 1 n, \infty)$ for all $m \geq n$. By hypothesis this implies $x \in f^{-1}[M-\frac 1 n, \infty)$ which means $f(x) \geq M-\frac 1 n$. Since this is true for each $n$ we get $f(x)=M$. 
Actually, characterization of compactness by finite intersection property shows that $f$ is necessarily bounded. [Consider the compact sets $f^{-1}[n,\infty)$].

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why $f$ is necessarily bounded? @Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: If $f$ is unbounded then $f^{-1}[n, \infty)$ is non-empty. These sets are closed subsets of a compact space, hence they are compact.. Also as $n$ increases so you can see  that these sets decease so the intersection of any finite number of them is also a non-empty compactness. This implies that the intersection of all these sets must be non-empty. But if $x$ belongs to each of these sets then $f(x) \geq n$ for all $n$ or $f(x)=\infty$, a contradiction..

Comment: Do you mean that the intersection of all of them must be $empty$? @Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: @user439126 If you have sequence of compact sets such that the intersection of any finite number of then is non-empty then the intersection of all of them is non-empty.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I was looking at $[n,\infty)$.

Comment: Are you implying that there are a finite number of $f^{-1}([n,\infty)$ as n goes to infinity? @Kavi Rama Murthy